# Firebase database not recognizing children

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my database is structured like this:

```
Categories
   Category1
      item1
         userData
            uid: someData
      item2
         userData
            uid: someData
      item3
         userData
            uid: someData
   Category2
      item1
         userData
            uid: someData
      item2
         userData
            uid: someData
      item3
         userData
            uid: someData
```

In my app I have two collectionViewControllers. The first one shows cells labeled category 1, category 2 etc. while the second collectionViewController should show cells with the items in each category.

The problem is that my app will not retreive the different items under the category nodes no matter how I try.

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Category1")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print(item.value)
        }
    }
```

In the example above, printing snapshot.children prints zero (twice, for some reason), and printing item in snapshot.children.allobjects prints nothing.

In the first collectionViewController, which references the Categories node, I'm able to retrieve the category1 and category2 data like this:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Categories")
    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for category in snapshot.children {
            let categorySnap = category as! DataSnapshot
            let categoryArray = categorySnap.key
            self.categoryArray.append(categoryArray)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I've tried this exact method in my seccond collectionViewController referencing the Category1 node, without printing anything, just adding it to the category array in the viewcontroller and reloading the collectionView. The cells still show up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass through every node to be able to retrieve data. In the first code snippet, you have the following:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Category1")
```

This won't retrieve anything because before `Category1`, you have node `Categories` which you didn't traverse through, therefore change it to the following:

```
ref = Database.database().reference("Categories").child("Category1")
```